# Why did Sauron have Amandil dismissed from Ar-Pharazôn's Council?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Before the coming of Sauron, Ar-Pharazôn allowed Amandil to be on his council, knowing he was one of the Faithful. However, when Sauron showed up, Ar-Pharazôn kicked him off the Council. I was wondering whether this had to do with Sauron, so that Amandil couldn't foil Sauron’s deceptive plans.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is given in the same paragraph in the *Akallabêth* that mentions this dismissal:

> In the days of their youth together Amandil had been dear to Pharazôn, and though he was of the Elf-friends he remained in his council until the coming of Sauron. **Now he was dismissed, for Sauron hated him above all others in Númenor**.

Earlier in the *Akallabêth* it's also said:

> And seeing the favour that he [Sauron] had of their lord all the councillors began to fawn upon him, save one alone, Amandil lord of Andúnië.

So yes, it was on account of Sauron and evidently because Amandil had not been corrupted and had not fallen under Sauron's domination.